# FirefoxDriver takes screenshots of different size

Tags: java, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-driver

I made a java application that compares screenshots taken from our staging environment against the production ones.
The app fails due to different screenshot sizes.

How can I define the screenshot size?
I am using the following code to generate the screenshot.

```
    final WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    try {
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
        driver.get(link);
        File outputFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    ....
```

Comment: Not with `OutputType.FILE`: [Javadoc] "TakesScreenshot makes a **best effort** depending on the browser to return the following in **order of preference**: 1) Entire page 2)Current window 3)Visible portion of the current frame 4)The screenshot of the entire display containing the browser."     There is another `OutputType.BYTES`. But fitting the screenshot by working with raw bytes is a task I would not want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Würgspaß mentioned in the comments, you can do this with OutputType.BYTE. Here is an example:

```
byte[] bytes = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
BufferedImage full = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
full.getSubimage(0, 0, 1200, 800);
```